# NavigationBarのバックボタンを押した時に、値を渡したい。

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

NavigationControllerでつないだ親画面A、子画面Bがあります。

私は子画面から親画面に戻る時に値を渡したいので

```
    <B ViewController>
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    let viewController = self.parentViewController as! A ViewController
    viewController.x = 1 //xはA画面の変数
}
```

のようにしました。
しかし

```
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'
```

とエラーが出ます。
この問題を解決するための方法を教えて欲しいです。

また上記の方法に代わる方法があれば
教えてもらえると助かります。

どうかよろしくお願いします。

---

一度、unwindを使いましたが私はnavi‌​gation barに出てくるbackボタンを押したときに値を渡したいんのですがunwindではできませんでした。

Comment: 回答の前提として、(1) プログラムだけで画面遷移したいのか、(2) Storyboardの編集を併用して、画面遷移したいのか、どちらなのか質問文に追記してください。(2)の方だと、Unwindで指定したActionメソッドを利用すれば、比較的簡単に値渡しができるので、個人的には、そちらがお勧めです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございますStoryboardを併用して画面遷移をしたいです。一度、unwindを使いましたが私はnavigation barに出てくるbackボタンを押したときに値を渡したいんのですがunwindではできませんでした

Comment: でしたら、質問文に、「backボタンを押したときに値を渡したい」旨を追記してください。質問のタイトルも変更していただくと、ベストです。通常のインターフェイスですと、バックボタンは、「何もしないで戻る」すなわちキャンセルボタンと同じ意味合いを持たせる設計が多いと思います。そうでないインターフェイスを実現しようというのですから、立派にひとつのトピックになりうる話題と言えるでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NavigationBarのBackボタンを押した時、おっしゃるとおり、UnwindセグエのActionメソッドは呼ばれません。しかし、`UINavigationControllerDelegate`の`navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)`は呼ばれるので、これを利用します。

*BViewController*

```
import UIKit

class NextViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
// クラス宣言に、UINavigationControllerDelegateを追加。

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // BViewController自身をDelegate委託相手とする。
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    // UINavigationControllerDelegateのメソッド。遷移する直前の処理。
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        // 遷移先が、AViewControllerだったら……
        if let controller = viewController as? AViewController {
            // AViewControllerのプロパティvalueの値変更。
            controller.value = 100
        }
    }

}
```

*AViewController*

```
import UIKit

class AViewController: UIViewController {

    var value: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("New value = \(value)")
        }
    }
    // プロパティオブザーバにする必要はないが、Delegateメソッドが働いていることを確認するため実装しています。

    // Other codes

}
```

---

> NavigationControllerでつないだ親画面A、子画面Bがあります。

`UINavigationController`ベースの画面遷移で、遷移元、遷移先の関係を親子と表現するのは、なじみがよくありません。`UIViewController`のプロパティ`parentViewController`は、エラーメッセージに述べられているように、親は`UINavigationController`になります。`AViewContoller`と`BViewController`は、子どうし、むしろ兄弟関係というべきでしょう。

> let viewController = self.parentViewController as! A ViewController

Swiftの書式では、変数名にスペースを含めることはできません。`A ViewController`ではエラーになるか、誤動作になります。`AViewController`とするか、アンダーバーを使って、`A_ViewController`としてください。